# Disabling Checkboxes after selecting the max selection using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make this multidimensional array checkbox to disable after selecting the max number of selection.

the problem is I don't know where the problem is in this jquery code.

Any kind of help is appreciated. thank you :D

here is my code.

```
<script>
$("input[name=chkservicecrew\\[<?php echo $ar_serviceID_count;?>\\]\\[\\]]").change(function(){
var max=  <?php echo $maxSelectedCrew;?>;
    if( $("name=chkservicecrew\\[<?php echo $ar_serviceID_count;?>\\]\\[\\]]]:checked").length == max ){
    $("name=chkservicecrew\\[<?php echo $ar_serviceID_count;?>\\]\\[\\]]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("name=chkservicecrew\\[<?php echo $ar_serviceID_count;?>\\]\\[\\]]:checked").removeAttr('disabled');
    }else{
    $("name=chkservicecrew\\[<?php echo $ar_serviceID_count;?>\\]\\[\\]]").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the solution below to handle such cases of checkboxes in dimensional arrays with change events.
I used object oriented javascript (jQuery in special) to nake it as clear as possible.This  will help you populate array's checkboxes with events attached with `initializeCheckboxEvents` method.

Take a look a the code. **BE CAREFULL** you have to add your php code where is needed to use at your case
http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/e0aL8aaz/

**In case of TWO DIMENSIONAL CHECKBOX ARRAY LIST**

```js
//Disabling Checkboxes after selecting the max selection using jquery
var Checkbox = function() {
  /// <summary>
  /// Checkbox class
  /// </summary>
  var testCheckboxId = "";
  var maxCheckboxesPerGroup = 2;
  var checkedBoxes = {
    0: [],
    1: [],
    2: []
  };

  function GetCheckboxId(input) {
    //takes the checkbox group id from the name chkservicecrew[0][] = 0
    var matches = input.match(/\[(\d+)]/);
    if (matches.length) {
      var num = matches[1];
      return num;
    } else return "";
  }

  function CheckIfMaximun(index) {
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if current checked checkboxes of this group id is equal to global MAX value maxCheckboxesPerGroup
    /// </summary>
    var checkedNum = $("input[name='chkservicecrew[" + index + "][]']:checked").length;
    //console.log(checkedNum.length);
    //console.log(maxCheckboxesPerGroup)
    if (maxCheckboxesPerGroup == checkedNum) {
      return true;
    } else
      return false;
  }
  return {
    Start: function(checkedBoxes) {
      /// <summary>
      /// Start by initializing on change events
      /// </summary>
      checkbox.Tools.initializeCheckboxEvents();
    },
    Tools: {
      initializeCheckboxEvents: function() {
        //Attaches on change events to all checkboxes depend on the group
        for (index in checkedBoxes) {
          $("input[name='chkservicecrew[" + index + "][]']").each(function() {
            //console.log(this);
            $(this).change(function() {
              //console.log(this.name);
              //get the group id
              var id = GetCheckboxId(this.name);
              //True if equal ,false if not
              var isMax = CheckIfMaximun(id);

              //console.log(isMax);
              if (isMax) {
                checkbox.Tools.DisableCheckbox(id);
              } else {
                checkbox.Tools.EnableCheckbox(id);
              }
            });
          });
        }
      },
      DisableCheckbox: function(checkId) {
        //Disables checkboxes that are not checked from checkid group
        $("input[name='chkservicecrew[" + checkId + "][]']:not(:checked)").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      },
      EnableCheckbox: function(checkId) {
        //Enables the checkboxes when checked are less than the global variable
        $("input[name='chkservicecrew[" + checkId + "][]']").removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    }
  };
};

//LETS START !!!
var checkbox = new Checkbox();
checkbox.Start();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.container input {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 25px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"><b>Group 1</b>

  <br/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='chkservicecrew[0][]' value='0' />chkservicecrew 00
  <input type='checkbox' name='chkservicecrew[0][]' value='1' />chkservicecrew 01
  <input type='checkbox' name='chkservicecrew[0][]' value='2' />chkservicecrew 02
  <br/><b>Group 2</b>

  <br/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='chkservicecrew[1][]' value='0' />chkservicecrew 00
  <input type='checkbox' name='chkservicecrew[1][]' value='1' />chkservicecrew 01
  <input type='checkbox' name='chkservicecrew[1][]' value='2' />chkservicecrew 02
  <br/><b>Group 3 </b>

  <br/>
  <input type='checkbox' name='chkservicecrew[2][]' value='0' />chkservicecrew 00
  <input type='checkbox' name='chkservicecrew[2][]' value='1' />chkservicecrew 01
  <input type='checkbox' name='chkservicecrew[2][]' value='2' />chkservicecrew 02</div>
```

**
**~ SOLUTION EDITION ONE ~**

**In case of ONE DIMENSIONAL CHECKBOX ARRAY LIST****

Let's say that `max  = 2;`
You want something like that (jQuery):

http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/z12wqLse/

```js
var maxCheckboxes = 2;

$('input[name="chkservicecrew"]').change(function() {
  var checkedNum = $('input[name="chkservicecrew"]:checked').length;
  var allCheckoxesChecked = $('input[name="chkservicecrew"]:checked');
  var allCheckboxes = $("input[name='chkservicecrew']");

  //alert(checkedNum + " - " + maxCheckboxes);

  if (checkedNum == maxCheckboxes) {
    $(allCheckboxes).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $(allCheckoxesChecked).removeAttr('disabled');
    alert("ooou equals and disable!");
  } else {
    $(allCheckboxes).removeAttr('disabled');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="chkservicecrew" value="the chkservicecrew" type="checkbox">chkservicecrew
<br>
<input name="chkservicecrew" value="chkservicecrew" type="checkbox">chkservicecrew
<br>
<input name="chkservicecrew" value="chkservicecrew" type="checkbox">chkservicecrew
<br>
<input name="chkservicecrew" value="chkservicecrew" type="checkbox">chkservicecrew
<br>
```

Hope you find that usefull :)!

Comment: You can add your php then.

Comment: umm, yup this will work but i need the checkbox to be a two dimensional array. welp still thanks for your help :D

Comment: @Gilbert I can say i tried my best! take a look the two dimensional edition.thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for taking your time answering this question. This code works too. :D

Answer (score 0):

After testing many times, i finally got the answer by myself x_x

```
<script>
$("input[name=chkservicecrew\\[<?php echo $ar_serviceID_count;?>\\]\\[\\]]").change(function(){
var max=  <?php echo $maxSelectedCrew;?>;
if( $("input[name=chkservicecrew\\[<?php echo $ar_serviceID_count;?>\\]\\[\\]]:checked").length == max ){
    $("input[name=chkservicecrew\\[<?php echo $ar_serviceID_count;?>\\]\\[\\]]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("input[name=chkservicecrew\\[<?php echo $ar_serviceID_count;?>\\]\\[\\]]:checked").removeAttr('disabled');
}else{
    $("input[name=chkservicecrew\\[<?php echo $ar_serviceID_count;?>\\]\\[\\]]").removeAttr('disabled');
}
});
</script>
```